# Paying cash into a EUR account in Italy (or another EU state)

Tags: international-transfer, eur-euro, european-union, italy

I am in Turin, Italy and I have some cash (EUR) that I would like to pay into my EUR account in a non-Italian bank (Polish in this case). The bank takes SEPA transfers. What is the cheapest and/or most convenient way of doing this?

Comment: If you have access to the necessary information, a European bank transfer with IBAN and BIC might be the easiest approach.